# How To Fix "Lexical declaration cannot appear in a single-statement context"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

when i make a embed and run the bot, the problem here appears cos i used a *let EmbedHelp = Discord.RichEmbed* this problems appears in the Terminal, please type the problem and what i need to fix :

```
SyntaxError: Lexical declaration cannot appear in a single-statement context
   at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
   at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
   at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
   at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
   at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
   at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
```

the code i use for the embed is :

````
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.startsWith('$Commands'))

    let EmbedHelp = Discord.RichEmbed()
        "title": "title ~~(did you know you can have markdown here too?)~~",
        "description": "```",
        "url": "https://discordapp.com",
        "color": 192748,
        "timestamp": "Timezone - GGT 3+",
        "footer": {
            "icon_url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/563449221701959700/8386d5fe48d71898c40244e7a5a66d58.png",
            "text": "footer text"
        },
        "thumbnail": {
            "url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/563449221701959700/8386d5fe48d71898c40244e7a5a66d58.png"
        },
        "image": {
            "url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/0.png"
        },
        "author": {
            "name": "Galak$y#3038",
            "url": "https://discordapp.com",
            "icon_url": "https://discordapp.com/channels/564059839320555540/569179399211974666"
        },

    }
});
channel.send({EmbedHelp})
````

Comment: It means what it says. `if (…) let EmbedHelp = …;` is invalid JS. What did you intend the conditional to do?

Comment: And is that whole bit under `EmbedHelp` supposed to be in a map?

Comment: If you're putting multiple statements inside `if` you need `{}` around them.

Comment: ... and if you're *not* putting multiple statements in the `if` then a `let` declaration would be almost completely pointless

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That error is referring to the line below `Discord.RichEmbed()`. You have an Object property declaration without any Object in sight. Looks like you're mixing up a few things that you tried to pull from the Discord docs.

[RichEmbed](https://anidiots.guide/first-bot/using-embeds-in-messages) is intended to be chained with other helper methods. If you instead put your code into an Object (wrapping it in curly braces `{}`) and pass it into an `send` method, it should get rid of that error.

````
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.startsWith('$Commands')) {
    message.channel.send({
      embed: {
        title: 'title ~~(did you know you can have markdown here too?)~~',
        description: '```',
        url: 'https://discordapp.com',
        color: 192748,
        timestamp: 'Timezone - GGT 3+',
        footer: {
          icon_url:
            'https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/563449221701959700/8386d5fe48d71898c40244e7a5a66d58.png',
          text: 'footer text',
        },
        thumbnail: {
          url: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/563449221701959700/8386d5fe48d71898c40244e7a5a66d58.png',
        },
        image: {
          url: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/0.png',
        },
        author: {
          name: 'Galak$y#3038',
          url: 'https://discordapp.com',
          icon_url:
            'https://discordapp.com/channels/564059839320555540/569179399211974666',
        },
      },
    });
  }
});
````

Comment: With the whitespace as it is, it seems unlikely to me that the solution here is obvious to all the people who would search for this answer.

Answer (score 6):

I had the following code:

```
                let viewShareSelectBoxInitializedInterval = setInterval(function () {
                    if (IsViewShareSelectBoxInitialized() === true) {
                        clearInterval(viewShareSelectBoxInitializedInterval);
                        ReloadViewShareItems(endItemStateIdForSharing);
                    }
                }, 250);
```

I changed the `let` to `var` and then it worked fine.

Locally on my development machine it would work with `let`, but when the JavaScript was bundled with using `let` it would fail.

Comment: That sounds far more likely to be my issue, since I just changed a bunch of `var` to `let`

Comment: Here's why it works with var but it doesn't with let in this case:

A var variable will be available throughout the function body in which it is defined, no matter how deeply nested its definition. A let variable will only be available within the same block where it is defined. 

Source: https://sentry.io/answers/difference-between-let-and-var-in-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

This error appears when some code block is not wrapped in curly braces `{}`.
The same happens to me when I was using the switch cases and the `case` block has multiple code lines.

e.g.

```js
    switch (type) {
      case 'invoice.finalized':
        const invoice = stripeEvent.data.object as Stripe.Invoice;
        await sendInvoiceEmail(ADMIN_EMAILS, invoice.customer_name, invoice.invoice_pdf);
        break;
      ...
    }
```

This code was giving me the same error: `Unexpected lexical declaration in case block  no-case-declarations`

So I fix this by wrapping the `case` block in `{}`. The correct code is

```js
    switch (type) {
      case 'invoice.finalized': {
        const invoice = stripeEvent.data.object as Stripe.Invoice;
        await sendInvoiceEmail(ADMIN_EMAILS, invoice.customer_name, invoice.invoice_pdf);
        break;
      }
      ...
    }
```

The same error happened in the question code `if` block that needs to be wrapped in `{}`.

This may also help to understand in details: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-case-declarations

Answer (score 0):

when you have a condition like if or else if, close the curly brackets {} like that below:

```
  function add (array, element){
    if(array.includes(element) === true){
    return array
 }
  else if (array.includes(element) === false){
   array.push(element)
   return array
 }
```

}